# How to calculate combinations when 1 or 2 out of each set is required?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm currently learning combinatorics and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. I do not understand how to solve the following question:

> Let's say that there is set A which has 10 numbers, set B which has 8 numbers, and set C which has 14 numbers. No two numbers are the same, they are all unique. Let's say we want to pick 7 numbers from the three sets, with the condition that we must pick at least one from set A, one from set B, and two from set C.

Do I use permutations or combinations for this task? My reasoning is that I should use permutations since all the numbers are unique, but I am not sure. How does this differ if we only needed at least one out of each set?
[This is how I would do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4WLZ.png)

Comment: No ordering of the "outcomes" is specified. What does that tell you? Oftentimes, one, or the other can be used anyway, depending on your thought process.

Comment: DavidP Is it combinations? I thought it was permutations because every number is unique
@RicardoCavalcanti My solution has been supplied in my main post, it makes sense to me, but usually I'm wrong when it comes to combinatorics lol

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted a coupple of days ago, Timothy?

Comment: Earth to Timothy; come in, please.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use permutations, and you don't use combinations; you use your brains to reason your way through the problem.

Here's one way. It may not be the best, but it should work.

First, if you ignore the restrictions, you're asked to choose seven things from $32$ ($32=10+8+14$), and you can do that in $32\choose7$ ways.

Now you have to throw out all the ways that don't meet the requirement of having at least one from $A$. That's $22\choose7$.

You also have to throw out the ones that don't meet the $B$ requirement. That's $24\choose7$.

Then you have to throw out the ones that don't meet the $C$ requirement. That's ${18\choose7}+14{18\choose6}$; the first term is the ways with nothing from $C$, the second term is the ones with exactly one from $C$.

So, so far we have $${32\choose7}-{22\choose7}-{24\choose7}-{18\choose7}-14{18\choose6}$$

But, wait – we've thrown out the ones violating the 1st requirement, and we've thrown out the one violating the 2nd requirement, which means we've thrown out the ones violating both requirements twice. We have to put them back in. That's $14\choose7$.

We also have to put back in the ones violating the 1st and 3rd requirements. That's ${8\choose7}+14{8\choose6}$.

And the ones violating the 2nd and 3rd requirements: that's ${10\choose7}+14{10\choose6}$.

In some problems of this type, we'd now have to remove the ones violating all three requirements, but there aren't any, so we're done. The answer is $${32\choose7}-{22\choose7}-{24\choose7}-{18\choose7}-14{18\choose6}+{14\choose7}+{8\choose7}+14{8\choose6}+{10\choose7}+14{10\choose6}$$